# What does this logic equation of overflow mean?

Tags: logical-operators

here is a paragraph from the textbook:

> When two's complement numbers are added or subtracted...Overflow is defined as the situation in which the result of an arithmetic operation lies outside of the number range that can be represented by the number of bits in the word...

> The logic function that indicates that the result of
> an operation is outside of the representable number range is:
> OVR = Cs XOR Cs+1 where Cs is the carry-in to the sign bit and Cs+1 is the
> carry-out of the sign bit.

I assume that by saying "sign bit" the author means the top bit. Now assume we have a 4-bit adder, 1100+1100, which leads to an overflow. The carry-in to the sign bit is 1 and the carry-out is also 1. This seems to contradict the formula. Where is the mistake?

Comment: There is no overflow. The result of 1100 (-4) + 1100 (-4) is 1000 (-8), which still fits in a 4-bit signed value.

Comment: @RaymondChen Ah you are right! Now if I pick 1000 + 1111, this gives -9 which is an overflow, and carry-in is 0 but carry-out is 1. Alright, solved! Thanks and happy holiday!

Comment: Please post the answer and accept it, so the system knows that the problem is solved

Comment: @RaymondChen done, have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer. Again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Please read the comments of the original question for more details)

In fact, as Raymond Chen mentioned, 1100+1100 does not cause an overflow, as the result still firs in a 4-bit signed value.

If we instead use 1000+1111, then the resulting -9 is indeed an overflow and we can observe the carry-in as 0 and carry-out as 1 for the sign-bit.